# Getting Turtlebot Heading

Tags: ros, pose, turtlebot, quaternion, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to get the heading of our turtlebot. We can get the Quaternion data about the robot's pose but want to convert to a simple euler angle. Is there C++ ROS code that is already available that supports this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30926/getting-turtlebot-heading/) by [zlalanne](https://answers.ros.org/users/2022/zlalanne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2012-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there is. Using the standard tf libraries:

```
tf:Quaternion q(x,y,z,w);
double yaw,pitch,roll;
btMatrix3x3(q).getEulerYPR(yaw,pitch,roll);
```

Yaw is what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7